# Very basic understanding on CRC algorithm. Length? Divisor?

Tags: algorithm, checksum, crc

Thank you for clicking my question.
I want to understand the CRC algorithm from the scratch.
I tried to read basic articles from Wikipedia and etc... but failed in some detailed points.

So, let me show one practical example case.
When we have to transfer the string `"HELLO WORLD!\0"` (let me call it as `[sz2]`) through the network,
also have to verify with CRC...
The `[sz2]`'s binary value should be like below: (and let me call it as `[ar3]`.)
`[01001000010001010100110001001100010011110010000001010111010011110101001001001100010001000010000100000000]`

Then, gotta perform a loop code to traverse `[ar3]`.
The first character is 'H' and binary is `[01001000]`

**Question1** : Shall i append `[000]` at the end of `[01001000]` and perform "XOR loop", then repeat the same job to the rest 12characters * 8bits chopped `[ar3]` to make different 13 CRC checksums?
Or, append `[000..]` at the end of `[sz2]` and perform the long traversing loop?

**Question2** : How to choose good `divisor`? what is adjacent polynomial for this case `[sz2]`?
Is there "commonly used polynomial" in general? Or, do we have to calculate through `[sz2]` to acquire good one?

**Question3** : Many explanation contents gives target binary starting with `[1...]`.
But as you can see `"HELLO"`'s `"H"` is starting with `[0100....]`.
then, if the divisor is `[1011]`, result of XOR becomes `[1111]`. What should be the next calculation?

Please teach me master hands; Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You append the three zeros once at the end of the entire message.
2. `1011` has been in common use for a degree-four CRC, e.g. in [ITU-T G.704](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/1-15.htm#crc.cat.crc-4-g-704). You can find an analysis for different message lengths on [Koopman's site](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Ekoopman/crc/crc4.html).
3. No, if the high bit is zero, there is no exclusive-or. The result of the first step is `01001000010...`. At the next step there is `1`, after which the result is `00010000010...`.